# Alphabetically Sort functions Sublime Text 3

Tags: javascript, formatting, sublimetext3

I have a set of functions defined in a file. They are arbitrarily ordered.

```
function foo() { 
  // func body
}
function bar() { /* func body */ }
function baz() { /* func body */ }
```

I would like some tool which will reorder them alphabetically by function name, i.e.:

```
function bar() { /* func body */ }
function baz() { /* func body */ }
function foo() { 
  // func body
}
```

(Note that simply sorting the lines of code alphabetically wont work.)

I'm interested in a general solution to this problem, as well as in my specific case—which is that I'm writing JavaScript and the editor I use is Sublime Text 3.

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Multi%20Select%20Alphabetizer - This may do what you are looking for... not able to test it while at work to actually see but let me know, I am curious on this as well

Comment: @NathanBlaine that's not the best solution in the world but its definitely better than nothing! If you make this comment into an answer I'll mark it as the solution until I find something better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Multi Select Alphabetizer sublime plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Multi%20Select%20Alphabetizer)
*might* be useful. Not able to test it at work so YMMV.

If you're feeling particularly adventurous you can try to convert this [Sublime plugin](https://github.com/foxxyz/sublime_alphpetize) from PHP to JS to fit your needs.... It's a bit surprising to me that a more general solution for this hasn't already been developed!

Best of luck.

Comment: The multiselect alphabetizer helps just to enough to be useful for my purposes! Thanks!

Comment: This plugin does nothing in my JS files. Literally nothing.